# Cannot build SSCatalog project

Tags: ios, sstoolkit

I'm having issues to build the SSCatalog project: https://github.com/samsoffes/sscatalog

I downloaded SSToolkit from: http://sstoolk.it/
but the Step 2 says "In Finder, drag SSToolkit.bundle located in Vendor/SSToolkit/Resources into the Resources folder in your Xcode project."
But there's no "SSToolkit.bundle" in the Resources folder... just .lproj folders, even though I build and run the SSToolkit project before.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'v solved the problem by just making a new bundle named SSToolkit.bundle, and then copy files under the sstoolkit/resources/images folder into it.

Answer (score 1):

The [installation guide](https://github.com/samsoffes/sscatalog) says

> To get the source code, run the following command:
>
> > $ git clone https://github.com/samsoffes/sscatalog.git --recursive